# Choosing a button with AngularJS and CSS does not work entirely

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, sass

Being a newbie in AngularJS/Cordova/Ionic I want to achieve different things when having clicked the "Eingepasst"-button, which will have a different logic compared to "Gewonnen" or "Verloren".

As being helped in another thread, I am now able to choose only one of "Gewonnen" or "Verloren" or "Eingepasst" (see screenshot). However when having clicked "Eingepasst" I am not able to click "Gewonnen" or "Verloren" anymore.

Here is the HTML-code:

```
<div class="padding">
    <div class="button-bar">
        <button ng-click="round.won=true" ng-class="{'active':round.won && !adjustedYesNo}" class="button button-outline">Gewonnen</button>
        <button ng-click="round.won=false" ng-class="{'active': !round.won && !adjustedYesNo}" class="button button-outline">Verloren</button>
        <button ng-click="adjusted()" ng-class="adjustedYesNo?'active':''" class="button button-outline">Eingepasst</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the relevant part of the CSS-file:

```
.button {

  border-radius: 10px;

  &.button-light {
    color: $ci-green;
  }

  &.button-outline {
    @include regular;

    color: $ci-white;
    border-color: $ci-white;

    &.activated {
      background-color: rgba($ci-white, .1);
      border-color: $ci-white;
    }

    &.active {
      border-color: $ci-white;
      background-color: $ci-white;
      color: $ci-green;
    }
  }
```

Finally the Javascript-code:

```
$scope.adjusted = function (adjustedYesNo) 
{
    $scope.adjustedYesNo = adjustedYesNo;
    console.log("adjusted before: ", $scope.adjustedYesNo);
    $scope.adjustedYesNo = true;
    console.log("adjusted afterwards: ", $scope.adjustedYesNo);
    return $scope.adjustedYesNo;
}
```

So what needs to be done here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="padding">
    <div class="button-bar">
        <button ng-click="round.won=true; adjustedYesNo=false" ng-class="{'active':round.won && !adjustedYesNo}" class="button button-outline">Gewonnen</button>
        <button ng-click="round.won=false; adjustedYesNo=false" ng-class="{'active': !round.won && !adjustedYesNo}" class="button button-outline">Verloren</button>
        <button ng-click="adjusted()" ng-class="adjustedYesNo?'active':''" class="button button-outline">Eingepasst</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try this. You need to set `adjustedYesNo` to false to show `active` class for `Gewonnen` or `Verloren`.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work entirely. With your code the ng-click-event behind "Eingepasst" is fired, but the colour for it does not change to white for the second, third time and so on. Respectively "Eingepasst" is not set to 'active'. It only works when having clicked the first time...

Comment: I can set the class to active as well as I can change the color when I click a button. I didn't test it using ionic or sass though. See this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/GMwHgd3JQDjuBzEJVS5M?p=preview

Comment: Thanks again for going the extra mile.